# output value of array to string in file

Tags: arrays, xml, powershell

I'm trying up update a URL in an XML file with the value of an array.

I'm outputting the computer name to a text file. I need to read that text file and input the contents into a string in an XML file.

Code:

```psh
$name = Get-Content 'C:\temp\hostname.txt'
(Get-Content "E:\Source\Igloo Upgrade to v5.0\Igloo Enterprise Distribution 5.0\Setup\Igloo Enterprise Administrator.SetParameters.xml") |
  ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '//twscheduler/','//$name/'} | 
  Set-Content "E:\Source\Igloo Upgrade to v5.0\Igloo Enterprise Distribution 5.0\Setup\Igloo Enterprise Administrator.SetParameters.xml"
```

The issue I have is it's inputting the word `$name` into the string instead of the value.

I've tried:

```psh
$name = Get-Content 'C:\temp\hostname.txt'
(Get-Content "E:\Source\Igloo Upgrade to v5.0\Igloo Enterprise Distribution 5.0\Setup\Igloo Enterprise Administrator.SetParameters.xml") |
  ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '//twscheduler/','//'$name'/'} | 
  Set-Content "E:\Source\Igloo Upgrade to v5.0\Igloo Enterprise Distribution 5.0\Setup\Igloo Enterprise Administrator.SetParameters.xml"
```

This errors with "unexpected token".

I've also tried:

```psh
$name = Get-Content 'C:\temp\hostname.txt'
(Get-Content "E:\Source\Igloo Upgrade to v5.0\Igloo Enterprise Distribution 5.0\Setup\Igloo Enterprise Administrator.SetParameters.xml") |
  ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '//twscheduler/',//$name/} | 
  Set-Content "E:\Source\Igloo Upgrade to v5.0\Igloo Enterprise Distribution 5.0\Setup\Igloo Enterprise Administrator.SetParameters.xml"
```

This errors with "missing expression after ','".

I'm pretty sure that I'm not escaping the array correctly so that it knows its an array and not just a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>    $_ -replace '//twscheduler/','//$name/'
> ```

PSH variables are not expanded in single quoted strings.

Try using a double quoted string instead:

```
$_ -replace '//twscheduler/',"//$name/"
```

Comment: PERFECT!! Thank you very much. Worked flawlessly!